# Can I downgrade my craft version from Client to Personal using the CP?

Tags: license

I have already downgraded from Craft PRO to Craft Client and am wondering if I can downgrade again from Craft Client to Craft Personal as the project I'm working on does not need anything more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. If you click the Settings icon in Craft, at the bottom of the screen you will see a box that reads:

> Upgrade Craft to take your site to the next level. Show me.

Click on that and a window will pop-up with the versions of Craft you can install. Yours will look like this:

[image]

Just click the **Uninstall** button and you will be downgraded to Craft Personal.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It worked for me but I think I hadn't permission to do it until I removed all client features from the CP beforehand

Comment: @itisconor No problem, glad you got it sorted.